# How to create optimized ruby?

Tags: ruby, performance

I read a tweet http://twitter.com/#!/bjschaefer/status/120519670515249152 saying about "Optimized ruby". 
Wondering how to create it?

Comment: +1 for linking to the actual tweet.

Answer (score 1):

As always when optimizing

- Measure
- Tweak
- Validate
- Repeat

Nothing special with optimizing Ruby and there are no hidden one click "optimize" buttons.